# Partitioning data.frame according to condition

Tags: r, partitioning

I have a data.frame shaped like:

```
c <- data.frame(name=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c","d","d"), value=c(1,3,2,4,5,3,4,5), address=c("rrrr","rrrr","zzzz","aaaa","ssss","jjjj","qqqq","qqqq"))
> c
  name value address
1    a     1    rrrr
2    a     3    rrrr
3    b     2    zzzz 
4    b     4    aaaa
5    c     5    ssss
6    c     3    jjjj
7    d     4    qqqq
8    d     5    qqqq
```

I am trying to split this data frame into two separate data frames according to one simple rule: group together people who didn't change address and group together people that changed address. Any hint on how to accomplish the task?

So far I am playing, with no avail, with:

```
for(i in seq(1,8, by=2)){
    print(i)
    print(unlist(c[which(c[i,3]==c[(i+1),3]),]))    
}
```

Comment: You should not use `c` as a variable as it is a builtin function for concatenating objects.

Comment: It's really a request for partitioning into non-overlapping subsets.

Comment: @BondedDust you mean I have to change the title or reword the question?

Comment: @SimoneGabbriellini: I added what I thought was the most accurate tag which does not seem to have stuck. Wiil try again, but changing the title to replace `subset` with `partition` might help searchers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This counts the number of addresses and splits on that basis. There is a hurdle to get over and it related to always getting `<NA>` from `ave` until using `as.character`. There was a warning message from which I'm copying the beginning, so searchers might be able to find this:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(1L, 1L)) :
```

The successful version (using a data-object named `cc`):

```
 split(cc,  ave(as.character(cc$address), cc$name, FUN=function(x) sum(!duplicated(x)) ) )

$`1`
  name value address
1    a     1    rrrr
2    a     3    rrrr
7    d     4    qqqq
8    d     5    qqqq

$`2`
  name value address
3    b     2    zzzz
4    b     4    aaaa
5    c     5    ssss
6    c     3    jjjj
```

If you really wanted a bipartite split then convert to logical with `> 1`:

```
 split(cc, ave(as.character(cc$address), cc$name, FUN=function(x) sum(!duplicated(x)) ) >1)

$`FALSE`
  name value address
1    a     1    rrrr
2    a     3    rrrr
7    d     4    qqqq
8    d     5    qqqq

$`TRUE`
  name value address
3    b     2    zzzz
4    b     4    aaaa
5    c     5    ssss
6    c     3    jjjj
```

I don't understand the comment. This is what I get as `str(dat)`:

```
List of 2
 $ FALSE:'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ name   : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 1 4 4
  ..$ value  : num [1:4] 1 3 4 5
  ..$ address: Factor w/ 6 levels "aaaa","jjjj",..: 4 4 3 3
 $ TRUE :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ name   : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 2 2 3 3
  ..$ value  : num [1:4] 2 4 5 3
  ..$ address: Factor w/ 6 levels "aaaa","jjjj",..: 6 1 5 2
```

Comment: The only drawback is that you got two lists back not two data frames, and using as.data.frames changes the columns names

Comment: I don't understand. First, I get one list. Second,  `dat[[1]]` and `dat[[2]]` should both be dataframes with the same column names as the source.

Answer (score 1):

using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
z<-c %>% group_by(name) %>% 
         mutate(changed = n_distinct(address))
split(z, z$changed)
```

Thanks to @akrun for reminding me of n_distinct

Comment: You could use `n_distinct` instead of `length(unique`

Answer (score 0):

@jeremycg's answer is great and I am trying to learn dplyr, but here is the non-dplyr version as well.

```
numAddresses <- sapply(split(c, c$name), function(x)
    length(unique(x$address)))
split(c, numAddresses[c$address])
```

Comment: Is this working? I get the whole dataset as the input

Comment: It works for me. You obviously have to store the split call into another variable if you want it to be saved, but the output of the split call should correspond to what was requested.